# The perimeter of a rectangle is $48$ m and its area is $135$ m$^2$. Determine the sides of the rectangle.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> The perimeter of a rectangle is $48$ m and its area is $135$ m$^2$. Determine the sides of the rectangle.

I tried the following:

Perimeter $=48$ m
Let the length be $x$ m and the breadth be $y$ m
 
As we know, Perimeter $=2(x+y)=48$
                     $\Rightarrow x+y=24$ $[\cdots (1)]$
Area$=135$ m$^2$.
As we know, Area$=lb$
Therefore, $135$ m$^2$ $=xy$ $[\cdots (2)]$

But, how do I solve this?

Comment: You can use equation (1) and eliminate $y$ from equation (2). This gives you a quadratic equation for $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x+y=24$

$x\cdot y=135$

Now solve for $y$ and substitute into the other equation.

$y=24-x$

$x(24-x)=135$

$-x^2+24x-135=0$

$x^2-24x+135=0$

$(x-15)(x-9)=0$

$x=15$ or $x=9$

Plugging back into original equation you will get $x=15, y=9$ or $x=9, y=15$. They can be interchangeable because it is a rectangle. What we consider the length or the width is arbitrary because we can simply rotate the rectangle to change perspective.

Comment: How do I take it on from there. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

$(x-y)^2=(x+y)^2-4xy=(24)^2-4.135=576-540=36$

Hence, $(x-y)=6$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I did not understand how you got (x-y)^2=(x+y)^2. Can you explain me?

Comment: $(x-y)^2=(x+y)^2-4xy$ : It is an identity, try expanding to check.

Comment: Nice way to do the problem. Minor glitch, $576-540=36$.

Comment: Thanks, minor but embarrassing.  :D